# ionic native calendar plugin - how to open and edit and event "interactively"?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native

The createEventInteractively method is very convenient using the create ui of the native calendar app and I was wondering if it is possible to open and edit an event "interactively"?

The ionic docs doesn't mention anything.

Answer (score 0):

you can use findevent methode to find it and then modify the event by using modifyevent

Answer (score 0):

This might help (ionic4):

```
import { Calendar } from '@ionic-native/calendar/ngx'

export class Class_Name {

   constructor (private calendar: Calendar) {}

  function() {
    this.calendar.createEventInteractively();
  }
}
```